# Why is it justifiable to go into coordinates when performing calculus of variations on manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, calculus-of-variations, stationary-point

Pretty much every time I see someone write down an action and find it's stationary points they immediately switch to coordinates and expand the Euler-Lagrange equations. Specifically, take the Einstein Hilbert action:

$$S=\int_M\langle Rc,g\rangle _g \text{dvol}_g$$
One usually writes down the volume form in coordinates, and the Ricci curvature in coordinates, then does some manipulation with Christoffel symbols to obtain the field equations:
$$Rc_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}=0$$
but why can we do this? I get that these objects are coordinate independent, but the integral is over all of $M$, so how does varying the action in a chart lead us to conclude that this is a global equation for $g$? Unless for some reason the integral should vanish on an arbitrary compact subset of a coordinate patch of $M$ I don't really see how to justify this, and I haven't seen a text which justifies this, but maybe it is trivial and I am just being dumb. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you compute the Euler-Lagrange equations, it suffices to consider only variations that are compactly supported within a coordinate chart.

Comment: @Deane why though?

Comment: The Euler-Lagrange equations are a system of PDEs. To find the equations at a particular point in the domain, it suffices to consider only variations that are nonzero in a neighborhood of that point. You might want to consider a simple example such as showing that on an open set $O\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, the Euler-Lagrange equations for $$\int_O |\nabla f|^2$$ is $$ \Delta f = 0.$$

Comment: @Deane But something like the Einstein field equations should yield a solution which is a globally defined metric on $M$. So we don't care just about the equations at a particular point, we care about them on the whole of the manifold.

Comment: A PDE is a pointwise equation involving a function (or tensor) and its derivatives. Such as $$\Delta f = 0.$$ But you usually want to solve such an equation at every point in the domain and not at just one point. The Euler-Lagrange equations are defined at each point on the manifolds, but you want a solution that holds at every point in the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this can have many reasons and I think this question is not dumb at all. Most common ones are:

Your manifold can be covered by $1$ chart, this for example includes space-time $\mathbb{R}^{3+1}$. In this case, you can choose global coordinates, in particular a nice volume form, and using your definition of integration on manifolds, the integrals coincide.

The next possibility is that there exists a globally defined object, which gives rise to something coordinate independent as you noted. In your case, everything is coordinate free: Curvature, metric tensor and a volume form. You just need to take care of the overlaps between two charts somehow. Hence by abuse of notation, you just write it in local coordinates under the integral. Intrinsic description are sometimes rather clunky and advanced, but they exist.
An example: Would you call the term $|d f |^2$ for a map $f:M \to N$ between manifolds a smooth section of the bundle $T^*M \otimes f^*TN \to M$ with metric induced by the metric on $g^{-1}$ on $T^* M$ and $h$ on $TN$? Or just write down some local coordiante expression involving $2$ metric tensors with index lowering/raising.

The last reason is: You really want to look at something locally. Some arguments, like regularity theory, only require you to look at solutions of certain PDEs locally. In this case, it is also often not mentioned and is often obscured, since global results are much harder to come by (and often understand). As also pointed out in the comments, the Euler-Lagrange equation are a point wise identity, so a local description (in some open subset) is enough.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is, if you have a (pseudo)-Riemannian metric which is already globally defined, and it locally satisfies the Einstein field equations, does it globally satisfy them? Also, I am not sure what you mean by $|df|^2$

Comment: Yes, if a globally defined metric satisfies the field equations in every coordinate chart, then it does so globally. The term I was referring to is the norm of the differential squared.

Comment: I think your last reason is the principal one. Particularly, such action principles in classical field theories, though often stated as being integrals over all of $M$, should really be considered as a collection of maps $S_K(\phi)$, for $K\subset M$ being a compact set in $M$ (say the closure of an open set with smooth boundary). The action principle should then be formulated as being stationary over all such $K$ (if we don't make this restriction, the original integral itself would be infinite, so there's no sense in which we can even vary it).

Comment: @F. Conrad clearly if it satisfies in every coordinate chart then it satisfies it globally, but if you only know one coordinate chart, does it follow that it satisfies in every coordinate chart if it satisfies it in the one you know? I’d assume probably not

Comment: @peek-a-boo if the manifold is compact this is not an issue

Comment: I think the first point in your second paragraph is the most convincing to me.

Comment: If a function/field satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation in just 1 chart, you cannot possibly know that it does so in any disjoint(!) chart. And as peek-a-boo pointed out, variation or Euler-Lagrange equations on manifolds is a rather technical to define. If you arent satisfied with this answer, you can either uncheck it (I don't mind) and/or repost this on physics SE.  However, I really suspet that doing these things in local coordinates instead of doing it coordinate free, is easier, even though it lacks rigor.

Comment: @F.Conrad it is significantly harder to do these things in a coordinate free way, at least for the Einstein-Hilbert Action. It is easy to do so for the Yang-Mills actions, or other actions that don't involve a variation of the metric. I think with $M$ compact, and choosing a finite set of coordinate charts  which leaves out sets of measure zero, then arguing from there using the coordinate independence of the objects makes some sense.